# Making an API in laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, api, laravel

I am a laravel beginner. I am building a PHP backend using laravel that will serve multiple platforms. I want to make an api that multiple platforms can use. This is what I am thinking of doing:

my api can be accessed like this: `URL.com/api/v1/login` (this responds in JSON)

and , if it a web version, login can be accessed from `URL.com/login`.This should display a form which will send an AJAX request to

```
URL.com/api/v1/login
```

I am thinking of setting up different routes for this. something like :

```
routes::post(api/v1/login,"whatever controller")
```

and

```
routes::get(login,"login_controller_which_will_send_ajax_requests_to the_above_controller")
```

I would like to ask something like this is recommended. if not, what is a better way to implement this

Comment: Not sure about "login_controller_which_will_send_ajax_requests_to the_above_controller", as the controller will never send ajax request. It is the javascript in the view rendered by the controller does the work.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant. The login controller that will call the view that will do the ajax request

Comment: And what do you mean by multiple platforms? Could you name them?

Comment: For now ,Android ,and ios. I'm curious as to why you ask.

Comment: As windows & mac are 2 platforms but could both use browsers, or their own native apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new route group with a prefix like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'],function(){

Route::resource('name', 'Controller'); //resource controller
});
```

in the controller initialize the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth.basic');
}
```

Using this one, the user will be able to access all the methods from here (index, store...) only after they send the username and pass as params.

If you mean that you need the proper login screen for a mobile device, create a new post method in a controller, where you get the username and the hash of the password, and in the case of matching username and password from the database, return the 200 HTTP response, else 403 (Forbidden). You don't need the AJAX requests here

Also before starting a project that uses a certain API, test everything using POSTMAN (all the get, post, put methods) and also verify if the authentification works or if a not logged in user can get/post data using your API. If you have questions write them here

Answer (score -1):

Suppose the multiple platforms you mentioned could be grouped as the website and mobile apps.

The recommendation is to build them separately: build the website like what you would do traditionally, and another api merely for mobile apps.

The reason is simple: For the website, you can use sessions to store user login status, but for mobile app, you need to use something like json web token to verify the user. It is going to be messy and hard to maintain if they share routes and actions.

Of course there are exceptions. If you built website as a web app using some JS framework like AngularJS, you may just build the api and serve them all.

Comment: Suppose the api itself handles the token(in case of mobile) and session(for web),will this work? I ask if this technique is ideal for laravel.

Comment: Then you need also consider the csrf token used by web, and maybe content negotiation for api, etc., which makes a controller action very heavy and hard to abstract. Also, to check the mobile token and web session for every request slows down the speed. So, the technique is workable, but may not be ideal for larger application.

Comment: Ok. Say I have two different URLS that will handle different platforms. URL.com/api/login.   And URL.com/api/mobile/login.  All mobile related routes will be routed to another controller

Comment: Cut it short. If you app is small, use one url; if big use two. So both will work.